# Print just the value of a dictionary term for a specific key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I am wondering what I do in Python if I have a dictionary and I want to print out just the value for a specific key.

It will be in a variable as well as in:

```
dict = {'Lemonade':["1", "45", "87"], 'Coke:["23", "9", "23"] 'Water':["98", "2", "127"}
inp = input("Select key to print value for!" + "/r>>> ")
if inp in dict:
    #Here is where I would like it to print the Value list for the key that is entered.
```

I am running Python 3.3

Comment: First step is to have a valid dictionary object.

Comment: Apologies. Did not have that intent.

Answer (score 8):

I have taken the liberty of renaming your `dict` variable, to avoid shadowing the built-in name.

```
dict_ = {
    'Lemonade': ["1", "45", "87"], 
    'Coke': ["23", "9", "23"], 
    'Water': ["98", "2", "127"],
}
inp = input("Select key to print value for!" + "/r>>> ")
if inp in dict_:
    print(dict_[inp])
```

Answer (score 6):

As Ashwini pointed out, your dictionary should be `{'Lemonade':["1", "45", "87"], 'Coke':["23", "9", "23"], 'Water':["98", "2", "127"]}`

To print the value:

```
if inp in dict:
    print(dict[inp])
```

As a side note, don't use `dict` as a variable as it will override the built in type and could cause problems later on.

Comment: That is of course just for the example. will dict[inp] work in Python 3.3?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
# A simple dictionary
x = {'X':"yes", 'Y':"no", 'Z':"ok"}

# To print a specific value
print([value for value in x.values()][1])
```

Output:

```
no
```